# Mover itens de coluna para coluna css grid

Tags: css, css3, front-end, grid

Quero saber se existe uma forma de mover um item dentro de uma coluna para outra coluna usando css grid. Segue exemplo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

aqui eu queria mover essa div verde para a segunda coluna da div roxa usando tags do css grid.

```
<div class="container">
  <header>header</header>
  <nav>menu</nav>
  <main>
    <div></div>
  </main>
  <span>span</span>
  <footer>footer<footer>
</div>


html, body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

header {
  grid-area:  headerr;
  background-color: pink;
}

nav {
  grid-area: navv;
  background-color: blue;
}

span {
  grid-area: spann;
  background-color: yellow;
}

main {
  grid-area: mainn;
  background-color: red;
}

main > div {
 width: 220px;
 height: 52px;
 background-color: green;
}

footer {
  grid-area: footerr;
  background-color: black;
}

.container {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas:
  'headerr headerr headerr headerr headerr headerr'
  'headerr headerr headerr headerr headerr headerr'
  'navv navv navv navv navv navv'
  'spann mainn mainn mainn mainn mainn'
  'spann mainn mainn mainn mainn mainn'
  'spann mainn mainn mainn mainn mainn'
  'spann mainn mainn mainn mainn mainn'
  'spann mainn mainn mainn mainn mainn'
  'footerr footerr footerr footerr footerr footerr';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Eu nunca vi alguém utilizando o grid-template-areas dessa forma, mas se você quer trocar as posições de elementos como divs basta utilizar grid-row nos itens para alternar entre cima/baixo e grid-columns entre esquerda/direita.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin:0;
}

.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  grid-gap: 3px;
  background-color: black;
}

.container > div {
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 50px;
}

.container > div:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color:green;
}

.container > div:nth-child(even) {
  background-color:blue;
}

/* Precisa explicitar a coluna atual da célula*/
.container > div:nth-child(2) {
  animation: baixo 2s infinite;
  grid-column: 2/3; /* Referenciando à segunda coluna */
}

.container > div:nth-child(5) {
  animation: cima 2s infinite;
  grid-column: 2/3; /* Referenciando à segunda coluna */
}

/* Trocando as posições */
@keyframes baixo {
  0% {grid-row: 1/2}
  100% {grid-row: 2/3}
}

@keyframes cima {
  0% {grid-row: 2/3}
  100% {grid-row: 1/2}
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Exemplo</title>
</head>
  <body>
  <div class="container">
      <div>1</div>
      <div>2</div>
      <div>3</div>
      <div>4</div>
      <div>5</div>
      <div>6</div>
      <div>7</div>
      <div>8</div>
      <div>9</div>
      <div>10</div>
      <div>11</div>
      <div>12</div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```